# Failed to use a R package via Rlink on Windows

Tags: packages, rlink

I need to import .ibw (Igor files.) into Mathematica.
For this I used 
1) to go in R via Rlink (OS windows), 
2) to load the package IgorR
3) to install it 
and then to use it.
Here is a script which use to work very well.
Then it suddenly stop working returning the following error :
Failed to retrieve the value for variable or piece of code library(IgorR) !
The IgorR package was not found !
Any ideas ?

```
Needs["RLink`"]    
InstallR[]    
RLinkResourcesInstall[]    
REvaluate["install.packages('IgorR')"]    
REvaluate["library(IgorR)"]
```

Comment: You are using the default R that comes with RLink, which is old, and also does not generally support well the installation of new packages (even though it usually works on Windows). I would suggest to try using your own R installation, which is generally more useful than the bundled R version, and gives you more freedom. You would need to install R separately, and use something like this: `InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.0", "RVersion" -> "3.4"]`.

Comment: Thank you  very much ! It works very well.

Comment: Happy to help. I will try to set out some time to update the bundled R distros for RLink (although, admittedly, bundled R is of pretty limited utility, compared to a standalone R).